# SharePoint 2013 Export To Excel - "An unexpected error has occurred."

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a SharePoint 2013 list that is working just fine in the web browser--I'm trying to get the "Export To Excel" function to work but am running into issues.  When I click the button in the SharePoint ribbon, it allows me to download an OWSSVR.iqy file.  If I open that file in Excel, it creates the connection to the SharePoint List and the data pulls just fine.  I can hit "Refresh All" and see the new data get populated.

However, if I save that spreadsheet and give it to a coworker and THEY hit Refresh All, they are met with this error:

> "An unexpected error occurred.  Changes to your data cannot be saved."

This also seems to happen if I give them the OWSSVR.iqy file directly and THEY open it in Excel.

My end goal is to have a spreadsheet that I can share with all of our team so that anyone can go in and hit Refresh All to pull the latest data from the SharePoint list.  What am I missing?

I'm  curious if it has something to do with permissions for the list?  I'm the owner of the SharePoint site so I have full control.  These other users merely have Contribute level access, so I'm not sure if that's causing the issue?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Oh boy, I have had so many weird random SharePoint errors that cause my to pull my hair out, so I feel for you. As you suggested, I would assume this has something to do with permissions. It might be deeper than that, like it is tied to your account, but I think that is unlikely. Out of curiosity, if they all have contribute access, why don't you just share the document with the whole team through SharePoint and let them access it that way? Isn't that the purpose of SharePoint? When you say you are sharing this file with them, do you mean through a locally mapped network drive, or by email, et

Comment: They all certainly have access to the list in Sharepoint, but the list basically holds all of the project proposals for the next year across several different teams.  We need a rep from each team to have access to the data in Excel spreadsheet form so that they can prepare reports, charts, and run some macros on the data.  I don't think there's any way to replicate that functionality within SharePoint.

Comment: A small development--if a user goes out to the SharePoint list and clicks the "Export to Excel" button, the .iqy file that they download seems to work just fine.  So perhaps it IS tied to the user.  I haven't tried running one of their files myself, but my gut tells me that I'll receive the error this time.  One potential fix, then, would be to create a view for each of them that shows all columns (we don't want that view to be public since it contains sensitive information).

Comment: What is wrong with them just downloading the file like that from SharePoint then? It sounds like they are able to perform all the functions you need, but you want to for some reason pass around a local file to do this? That's what we do at my company, and that's why that feature exists on SharePoint.

Comment: The main reason is because when you Export to Excel, the export only includes the columns that are in the current view.  In our public views, we only have a handful of summary-type columns visible because there are well over 100 people submitting ideas to the list.  But there are almost 70-80 calculated fields (many of which contain sensitive information about idea viability, patent info, etc.) that we don't want all 100 people to see.  And I don't know any way to make a list view that I can assign permissions to on a person-by-person basis.  Is that possible?

Comment: Do you need specific permissions for each person or for two types of people: people who can view the sensitive information and people who can't? You could make two user groups and set permissions respective to those groups.

Answer (score 4):

I have encountered this issue in the past as well, and it was very frustrating until I found out what was causing it.  If you export a list from a personal view to Excel, the user who's view it is can open and refresh the data on the spreadsheet just fine, but anyone who the spreadsheet is shared with will not be able to refresh the data as they don't have "permission" to see the view within SharePoint.  Make sure that the list view you are using when exporting to excel is a public view and this issue should be resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion--unfortunately I no longer have access to this SharePoint as I've changed jobs.  I'll pass it on to my replacement, though, and see if he can get it to work.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue today with the Export to Excel not allowing others to click refresh and getting the following error:
"An unexpected error occurred. Changes to your data cannot be saved."
To fix I made sure that the Connection Definition was not using the connection file (Always use connection file was unchecked) and I actually created a second excel file with a connection to the same list, ensured that it worked when saving from different people and then copy and pasted the connection string and command text from the working one to the original one I wanted to fix.  This seemed to work.  Excel data connections to Sharepoint seem finicky and I could not discover what the root cause of the original file not refreshing was.  Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of permissions. The user who is trying to open the (.iqy) file should be also added in site or site collection. Try after adding the user. I faced the same issue and it helped :).

Answer (score 0):

I received this message "An unexpected error occurred. Changes to your data cannot be saved." when I would attempt to refresh the table (linked to a SharePoint list). I was using a connection file saved in a data connections library and I am glad I did. When I ran the connection file in the data connections library, I got the same error. I was able to solve the problem by re-exporting the view to excel and overwriting the existing connection file in the data connection library. The excel file with the original exported list refreshed without error after that.